# SSL credentials for sending mail from gmail account in powershell code

Tags: email, powershell, ssl

```
 $smtpServer = "smtp.gmail.com"
    $smtpport = "465"
    $username = "gmailid@gmail.com"
    $password = "gmailpassword"
    $smtp.EnableSSL = $true
    $smtp.credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($Username, $Password);
    $smtp = New-Object System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient($SMTPServer, $SMTPPort);
    $msg = New-Object Net.Mail.MailMessage
    $msg.To.Add($user)
    $msg.From = "gmailid@gmail.com"
    $msg.Subject = "Local Environment DiskSpace Report for $titledate"
    $msg.IsBodyHTML = $true
    $msg.Body = get-content $diskReport
    $smtp.Send($msg)
    $body = ""
```

Here user is must be define in other way like

```
    $users = "scondgmailid@gmail.com"
```

But while run file of powershell bat file getting error:

```
    $smtp.EnableSSL = $true

    CategoryInfo : InvalidOperation:<:>[],RuntimeException 
    FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyNotFound
```

Same error also on :

```
    $smtp.credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($Username, $Password);
```

Please solution on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First new the object, then set the properties:

**`$smtp = New-Object System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient($SMTPServer, $SMTPPort);`**

`$smtp.EnableSSL = $true
 $smtp.credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($Username, $Password);`
    <s>`$smtp = New-Object System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient($SMTPServer, $SMTPPort);`</s>